# Matplotlib: How to prevent Jupyter from squeezing a large graph into a single cell?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

Any time I try to plot a large graph  in Jupyter with Matplotlib, where I would wish to scroll around the large image in the cell it has been rendered in, the notebook seems to squeeze the plot down to fit within its cell.

Normally, this is an optimal behavior, but how could I turn this off when I need to? How could I make plots display in their correct dimensions, given the `ppi` of one's screen?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the magic function `%matplotlib inline` ?

If so, you may be able to adjust either figure size or resolution to resize accordingly.

Adjust Figure Size (tends to distort text):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
```

Global Option:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 15]
```

Adjust Resolution (doesn't distort text):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200
```

---

### Edit

Use the dropdowns: cell > all output > toggle scrolling (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: The question that is asked here is: Given a figsize of 15,15 and a dpi of 200, a figure with dimensions 3000 by 3000 pixels is produced. This figure is shrunk by jupyter to fit into the notebook width. So OP wants to know how to add scrollbars in the output cell, such that the figure is kept in its desired size?